# Google Vis and shiny loading charts

Tags: javascript, r, google-visualization, shiny

I have made a page in shiny that has a side and main panel. The side panel lets you chose the dataset and the main panel has some text on top and then a googlevis chart followed by some text at the bottom.

Every time the dataset is changed and the chart reloads, it dissapears for a bit while its loading making the text at the bottom move up the page until the chart finally displays again. Then the text moves back to the bottom.

My question is, is there a way to have a placeholder while the chart is loading so you dont get that ugly text moving while the chart loads? Or is there a way to split up the main panel so the chart can reload without bothering the text below?

Answer (score 0):

Shiny provides a good introduction to laying out your shiny app http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/layout-guide.html

You might be looking to use something like the grid format where you can divide the main screen into a grid cells (big surprise there, huh) and place different content in each cell.

From the layout guide, it looks like this is implemented through the fluidRow() function, within which you specify each column() and its characteristics.

```
mainPanel(
           fluidRow(
             column(12,
                    p("THIS FLUID ROW TAKES UP THE ENTIRE WIDTH OF THE PAGE"),
                    br(),
                    br(),
                    br())),
           hr(),
           fluidRow(
             column(4,
                    p("THIS FLUID ROW IS DIVIDED INTO THREE COLUMNS, EACH 1/3RD OF THE PAGE WIDTH"),
                    img(src = "bigorb.png", height = 72, width = 72)),
             column(4,
                    p("THIS IS THE SECOND COLUMN"),
                    img(src = "bigorb.png", height = 72, width = 72)),
             column(4,
                    p("THIS IS THE THIRD COLUMN"),
                    img(src = "bigorb.png", height = 72, width = 72))
             )

)
```

Comment: I have tried using columns in fluid row, it divides the main panel vertically which is a nice feature, but I cant divide it horizontally which is what I want.

Comment: I guess I don't understand your question then.  The fluidRow function allows you to divide the page into rows.  The column function inside the row function allows you to create columns.  If you want to divide the page into two columns, you simply add one fluid row (thus height = total page height) and add two columns. If you want two rows (each 1/2 of the total page height) then add 2 fluidRows and use 1 column with a width equal to 12 (this is the full page width).  I have added some code to my answer to help you out.